# Why instantiate a ServiceHost within BackgroundWorker for a WCF service hosted within a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, backgroundworker

I have a Windows service that I created to host a WCF service.  It works no problem, but I've noticed online that a lot of people build their services such that the servicehost object is instantiated within a BackgrounWorker.  I was just wondering what the reasoning/advantages to using this pattern would be?

Here's an example of what I mean.

```
{
     internal static ServiceHost myHost = null;
     BackgroundWorker worker;

     public Service1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
     {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
     }

     void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (myHost != null)
        {
           myHost.Close();
        }
        myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServicetohostinWindow.Service1));
        myHost.Open();
     }
}
```

Comment: Read about it and tell me also :) why doing so if you can set the ServiceBehavior to open new thread on each call ? maybe for async reasons ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is done to unblock OnStart method, which is usually invoked when service starts. Constructing and opening new service host may be a long operation, and service will not report itself as started until OnStart is completed. There is a timeout on how long service can be in 'starting' state, so it is essential that OnStart be as quick as possible.